# Suspicious sql injections via site search

Tags: magento-1.9, database, security

On my Magento site, I clicked on Search Terms to see what is popular and I noticed what you see below several attempts of SQL injections. Can someone point out what damage they could have done and how to stop them?

```
--Apple' union select 0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a
--Apple' union select 0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a 
--Apple' union select 0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a 
--Apple' union select 0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a 
-- Apple' union select 0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a 
-- Apple' union select 0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a 
-- Apple' union select 0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a 
-- Apple' union select 0x5e252a,0x5e252a,0x5e252a 
-- Apple' union select 0x5e252a,0x5e252a 
-- audio bag Barkan
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Everything I wrote in the linked duplicate applies here too, although the queries are different.

Comment: What they seem to try is to determine how many rows a search SQL query selects to then continue with the attack. But Magento is safe against this attempt.

Comment: I believe @fschmengler meant that **stock core** magento was impervious to this attack.  Your third party extension mileage may vary :-\